# Best bibliography on the classic Merton portfolio problem

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, portfolio, books

I am writing a small section on my thesis about the classic Merton portfolio problem.
I was wondering what are the best books on the subject.

I am looking for something from the beginner to the intermediate level.

Comment: This bachelor thesis presents the Merton Portfolio Problem starting from a fairly elementary point of view https://tesi.luiss.it/17083/1/184031_CARBONE_ANGELO.pdf  You can skip what you already know.